# How do I get steam to finish updating my game?

Tags: steam

I want to format my pc, so I need to back up my games on steam and I cannot back up until they are up-to-date. Now steam does not want to update my game, it needs 91.9 MB and steam gets up to 58.1 MB and just decides to stop downloading.

The update is not paused, steam doesn't pause the update, just gets stuck at 58.1 MB and says 13% complete. 
It's not my internet connection, I have tried re-installing steam and restarting my pc. I cannot re-install the game as it is 17Gig or something ridiculous.

Comment: How long have you waited when the update got stuck?

Comment: Do you have enought disk space left on C or Steam hard drive?

Comment: I got fed up and just left it will have to re-install the game again when I am at a relative with uncapped. I left it open because I realize some other people might be having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your primary concern is to take backup of games you can directly Copy the **Whole** steam folder located in c:/Program files/ to a HDD. This will do the same job you , to restore you just copy it in again from HDD to program files and open steam, steam will again download the client and then you can try to update the game . Also as you mentioned steam backup it is not quite reliable , I once tried but Had to download whole 16 GB game again! Above method works flawlessly!

Comment: This does not work anymore as steam can only recover game files through back up. I tried this with another game about 2 months ago (Like I usually do) and Steam told me to update the game but it was the 15 odd gigs so basically re-installing it.

Comment: @Daniel You sure?  only 15 days ago I did this for Dota2. I did same what I have mentioned above.

Comment: that's interesting because I am referring to Dota 2 in my previous comment, I did what i usually do and copy the files over to the new location and the validate the files from steam, but when I did this it said files validated and then said it needs to update in which case it re downloaded it.

Comment: So it seems we did the same thing and came out with opposite outcomes, my back up usually works (not 100% as you said) but the file copying not so much and for you it's the other way around... lol

Comment: @Daniel Yep I guess so , Copying the files have always worked for me for Dota2 and GTAiv but backup didn't worked of both of them (It just made some progress and just stopped,Tried numerous times but no avail). I guess we have our own workarounds. LOL

Comment: So I did this now with another game and it worked well, so going to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Daniel Congrats

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things you could try, from the [Steam Solving Download and Game Installs support page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6966-IADH-1503):

> ## Change your download region
>
> Try launching the stalled game by double clicking it.  This may allow
>   the download to finish.
>
> If the issue persists, please double check your current download
>   region:
>
> - Start Steam
> - Go to Steam > Settings > Downloads tab
> - Under Download region, select the region that you are in or that is closest to you.
> - You can also try various regions near your location to see if a better connection is available.
>
> ## Router Issues
>
> The issue is usually from a router interfering with the download
>   process. Please unplug your router and connect your computer directly
>   to your internet connection to test the issue.
>
> If this corrects the issue, please resolve the router issue using this
>   guide: [Troubleshooting Network Connectivity](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1456-EUDN-2493)
>
> ## Connection Speed
>
> Make sure your Internet Connection setting is correct for your current
>   connection: In the Steam application, Click Steam > Settings >
>   Downloads tab and make sure the speed is correct, as incorrect
>   settings may affect your Steam downloads.
>
> ## Still not working?
>
> You can also try [clearing your download cache](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3134-TIAL-4638).
>
> Or the issue could be due to another program interfering with Steam. 
>   Please complete these guides to further test the issue:
>
> [Programs Which May Interfere with Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289)
>
> [Disabling Background Applications](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8043-EUJN-5239)

Comment: Once I had an update in which the game included an enemy named "attack cloud". The update got blocked by my antivirus. Maybe this could be similar in this case, so one possible solution is to deactivate the antivirus and retry to download the update.

Comment: @Denelio I disable my antivirus whenever I launch steam, and re-activate when I log-out. So I doubt this to be the case.

Comment: @Nzall I did mention it is not the connection that was the problem as I was  able to stream HD Youtube - I did this to check the connection. There is only two areas that are remotely close to me; the first is about 100km away (Current) and the other being other side of the country like 2000km away... I went through this guide before I consulted here.

Answer (score 1):

> Now steam does not want to update my game, it needs 91.9 MB and steam gets up to 58.1 MB and just decides to stop downloading.

Depending on the type of content steam may just download "patches", chunk of content that needs to be applied to your files. That way, it may appears that steam stopped downloading but it is actually working on updating the files.

Steam also use an algorithm to compress the downloaded data, which then needs to be uncompressed locally. Be sure that when steam stop downloading, nothing else is going on (no cpu activity, no hard drive activity) - in short, be certain that the problem is your network. If it is not the network, then all you need to do is wait for steam to finish its job.

If it is a network issue, then follow Nzali recommendations.

Sources:

- http://store.steampowered.com/news/5856/
- https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamPipe

Comment: I researched this at fist so I let it run for a while (4H) and when I came back.... still 58.1. This is when I restarted steam, my pc etc and consulted here.